# How to find the nth bit of an integer in C

Tags: c, binary, twos-complement

I've got an assignment where I need to convert from an 8 bit sign magnitude number to two's complement and then add those two numbers. I've got a relatively good idea as to how to do this, however I can't work out how to find the eighth bit of an integer such that I can tell what sign the number has.

The overall idea is that should the sign bit be 0 just return the number as it is already in two's complement if it is a one though then I want to set it to 0 before inverting all bits with the ~ operator and then add 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your effort until now.

Comment: Hmmm... if the last bit in a signed variable is 1 then `x < 0` should be true... you don't have to check the specific bit.

Comment: You can use `&` for this.  `0b01111111 & bits`, this way the result will have the eighth bit set to 0, regardless.

Comment: "... then add those two numbers" and represent the answer how? In which format? Two's complement?

Comment: Which two numbers to add are you referring to?  The same number in both sign-magnitude and twos-complement format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the high bit is set by creating a mask that has just that bit set and using a logical AND to see if the result is non-zero.

Once you know the high bit is set, you can convert to twos complement by flipping all bits and adding one.

```
uint8_t x = (some value)
if (x & (1 << 7)) {
    printf("sign bit set\n");
    x = (uint8_t)((~(x & (0x7F))) & 0xFF) + 1;
    printf("converted value: %02X\n", x);
}
```

Then you can add this number to any other normally.

Comment: Or just `int8_t result = x & 0x7F; if(x & (1<<7)) result = -result;` More readable and potentially slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your computer/compiler uses two's complement (almost certainly the case) and assuming that you want the result to be in two's complement.

Use an `uint8_t` to hold the sign and magnitude number.

To check if a bit is set, use the bitwise AND operator `&`, together with a bit mask corresponding to the msb. To get a bit mask corresponding to bit *n*, left shift the value 1 *n* times. In C code:

```
#define SIGN (1 << 7)

uint8_t sm = ...;
if(sm & SIGN)     // if non-zero, then the SIGN bit is set
{
}
else              // it was zero, the SIGN bit is not set
{
}
```

To do the actual conversion, there are several ways. I simply would mask out and copy the relevant parts of the number, again with bitwise AND:

```
#define MAGNITUDE 0x7F

int8_t magnitude = sm & MAGNITUDE; // variable magnitude is two's compl.
```

---

EDIT complete solution (since someone already posted one):

```
#define SIGN (1 << 7)
#define MAGNITUDE 0x7F

uint8_t sm = ...;
int8_t  twos_compl = sm & MAGNITUDE;

if(sm & SIGN)     // if non-zero, then the SIGN bit is set
{
  twos_compl = -twos_compl;
}

int8_t x = ...; // some other number in two's complement
int16_t result = twos_compl + x;
```

---

As a side note, be very careful when mixing the `~` operator with small integer types, because it performs an implicit integer promotion. For example `uint8_t x = 1` and then `~my_uint8` gives you 0xFFFFFFFE (32 bit system) and not 0xFE as you might expect.

For the above task, there is no need to use `~` at all.